# How to send sites mailer.php emails through Google Apps

Tags: php, email, google-apps

I have a site where users create profiles. They are prompted to confirm their emails via a confirmation email.

I am on a hostgator vps and have a google apps account. There is a mailer.php file in my site files, and it has a PHP script that runs to send out the confirmation email. However, this email is sent through my hostgator VPS and uses my local IP as the send IP.

What's needed in order to send all of this outgoing mail through my google apps account? I'm thinking its a re-written php script.

Comment: any mail script worth its salt would have an option to specify a server name/account, instead of just depending on a local SMTA

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do a SMTP connection to the google apps account for sending eMails via google apps. Google supplies SMTP connection data in their helpcenters.

A SMTP library for PHP could be something like the [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer).